# What is the language used in this script?

Tags: programming-languages

I have some code that i am supposed to work on as an assignment.But i am having trouble figuring out what it is written on.I normally code in c# but this is like nothing i've ever seen.

```
<cust_name "Reservations Cancelled Report">

<start_form "CANCRESV">

< t = 51>
<set_field n = 50>
<set_field o = 200>
<set_field h = 1300>

<set_print_lines = 55>

<loop>
  <concat {t[1]} = {3}>
  <box 10,10,14,70>
  <writpos 0,12,20, "Reservation cancellations for : ">
  <getfield 5,2,12,52,9,1>
  <if {20[{t[1]}]} >= 0>
    <calc {n[1]} = {20[{t[1]}]}>
    <break_loop>
  <end_if>
  <error "Invalid date">
<end_loop>

<concat {t[2]} = "16,'" + {26[{20[{t[1]}]}]} + "'">
<exec {h2[{t[2]}]}>              ! Init for Reservation history search

<loop until_last_page>
```

Comment: So why are you tagging it as C#?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I was unsure what to tag it exactly.Sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you for the edit.

Comment: i put <start_form in google and got sapscript

Comment: Maybe it is BobX, or some WTF like it. http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/We-Use-BobX.aspx
Hard to tell without context.

Comment: @Cesar can you not ask whoever gave the assignment?

Comment: My research Also Points in that direction.However i was looking for confirmation from the Coding gurus in here,just to be sure

Comment: @Purplegoldfish It's supposed to be a test And i have to do my own research

Comment: Well, I don't recognize it, but it looks awful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a rarely used language call Splud.

It is mainly used to wind-up students and trainees, and annoy online communities.

On occasion, it has been identified with other random (hitherto unknown) programming languages but these classifications are rarely accurate and are usually cynical intentions to illicit reputation points, or other virtual currency.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A quick Google search came up with no relevant results.Could you please post a link to some documentation please.

Comment: Everything you need is here: https://www.google.com/search?q=irony&rlz=1C1CHVN_enDE552DE552&oq=irony&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1783j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8